# ODBC connection worked in VWD 2010 debug but not in release

Tags: odbc

Here are my codes:
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
    Dim SoItem As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim ODBCConnection As New OdbcConnection("dsn=SBT")

    Try
        Dim MyAdapter As OdbcDataAdapter
        MyAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter("select distinct glsale from sotran01", ODBCConnection)
        MyAdapter.Fill(SoItem, "sotran01")
        ODBCConnection.Close()
        Label1.Text = SoItem.Tables("sotran01").Rows(0)("glsale").ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.Text = ex.Message
    End Try

End Sub
```

This is running on Window 2008 Server 64bit and the ODBC driver (MS FoxPro VFP Driver) is installed in odbcad32.

I was able to read from the table in debug mode but not in release. 
Thank you in advance for your help.
Thank you.
Michael

Comment: You haven't given any information. What error message do you get (if any)? Does the DSN you're using exist for the user your release version is running as?

Comment: Hi Ken, This is the error msg "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ". DSN is in both user and system.

Answer (score 0):

In 64 bit systems there are two `odbcad32`: one for 32 bit applications (`c:\windows\syswow64`) and one for 64 bit applications (`c:\windows\system32`). Make sure your DSN is visible in both and try again.